# How do I activate Network Manager on Debian?

Tags: networkmanager

The NetworkManager has stopped working, and I can't seem to get it to start running again. If checking the status is says masked and inactive (dead).
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you run the following command:

```
sudo service network-manager start
```

Comment: Nothing, there is no output. What should happen with this?

Comment: Now, Please post output of "sudo service network-manager status" command(without quotes)

Comment: The output is `Network-Manager.serivce - LSB:  network connection manager   //  Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/network-manager; generated; vendor preset: enable   //Active: active (exited) since Sat 2019-05-04 19:18:30 UTC; 9h ago                 //                      Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)                    //                                                                       Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)                                            //                                                                            CGroup: /system.slice/network-manager.service`

Comment: And `May 04 19:38:39 Cato systemd[1]: Starting LSB: network connection manager. `          `May 04 19:38:39 Cato systemd[1]: Started LSB: network connection manager. `

Comment: What does "journalctl -xn" say?

Comment: It says `Hint: You are currently not seeing messages from other users and the system. Users in the 'systemd-journal' group can see all messages. Pass -q to turn off this notice. //  No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions. `

Comment: See this link: https://serverfault.com/questions/806469/how-to-allow-a-user-to-use-journalctl-to-see-user-specific-systemd-service-logs

Answer (score 0):

Something has put a "mask" on the Network-Manager service.  If you want to try and remove the mask:

```
systemctl unmask Network-Manager
systemctl enable Network-Manager
systemctl start Network-Manager
```

(These commands need root privilege. E.g. you might want to run them as `sudo systemctl ...`)